# ? Operator Does Not Work

Tags: java, operators

How come this is not possible? I am getting illegal start of expression.

```
(s1.charAt(i) == ' ') ? i++ : break;
```

Comment: does this work if you have it in a [while, for, w/e] loop?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The thing to understand here is that the **?:** operator is used to **return a value**. You're basically calling a function that looks like this in that line:

```
anonymous function:
    if(s1.charAt(i) == ' '):
        return i++;
    else:
        return break;
```

Makes no sense, right? The **?:** operator was only designed as a shorthand for if/else return statements like the above, not a replacement of if/else altogether.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot use `break` in part of a ternary conditional expression as `break` isn't an expression itself, but just a control flow statement.

Why not just use an if-else construct instead?

```
if (s1.charAt(i) == ' ') {
    i++;
} else {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The ternary operator is an expression, not a statement. Use `if ... else ...` for this.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it works. But it's an operator. Since when was a statement such as 'break' an operand?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend avoiding the ternary (?:) operator EXCEPT for simple assignments. In my career I have seen too many crazy nested ternary operators; they become a maintenance headache (more cognitive overload - "don't make me think!").

I don't ban them on my teams, but recommend they are used judiciously. Used carefully they are cleaner than a corresponding if/else construct: -

```
public int ifFoo() {
    int i;

    if( isSomethingTrue()) {
        i = 5;
    }
    else {
        i = 10;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Compared to the ternary alternative: -

```
public int ternaryFoo() {
    final int i = isSomethingTrue()
                ? 5
                : 10;

    return i;
}
```

The ternary version is: -

- Shorter
- Easier to understand (my opinion, of course!)
- Allows the variable to be "final"; which simplifies code comprehension; in a more complex method, someone reading the code knows no further code will try and modify the variable - one thing less to worry about.

Comment: `return isSomethingTrue() ? 5 : 10;` is sooo much cleaner that 10 lines if statement and that useless local variable.

Comment: I only put the local variable in so I can breakpoint on that line if I ever need to debug. Not too fussed, either way!

Comment: The variable can be final either way actually, as long as it is assigned via all code paths before use.